# How to change Unix Line feed to Windows Line Feed with C#

Tags: c#, .net, newline, linefeed

I'm trying to write a unix2dos program to alter the line feeds of text files. 
The problem is instead of altering the contents of a text file, the file name was appended instead.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace unix2dos
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\textfiles\", "*.txt");

            foreach (string file in filePaths)
            {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    string replace = line.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
                    File.WriteAllText(file, replace);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are writing the string and overwriting it.

Try this:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\textfiles\", "*.txt");

foreach (string file in filePaths)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
        List<string> list_of_string = new List<string>();
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        list_of_string.Add( line.Replace("\n", "\r\n"));
    }
    File.WriteAllLines(file, list_of_string);
}
```

Comment: you were writing one line at a time into the file and overwriting the file, instead of getting all the lines, and writing them once at the end.

Comment: i really had no idea about lists. Thanks again

Comment: You can achieve the same without list, you simply need to append to the file. Have a look here [msdn append page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: It failed in my case because there was mix of of linux and windows. It also fails if you run it 2x because it does not check current line ending. It will produce \r\r\n which is not correct.